# What element is on the center?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

There is a list made by ng-repeat with a lot of row.

```
 <ul ng-repeat="element in elements |  filter:filterQuery">
    <a class="row" >
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class="caption">
                <h4>{{element.artists[0].name}}</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</ul>
```

I would like to find which element (vertical) is in the center of the screen.[image]

Could you help me with that? I'm new in Angular.
I belive the problem is similar to infinite scroll. but instead of finding last element there is need to find element in the center

Comment: Is there always an element in screen center? Does center mean exact center? Do you need to apply class to found element? Depending on these details I might be able to help you.

Comment: There is a space between elements so not always is on the center, but I can aproxymat it. It would be nice if that could be exact center, but not nessesary. I need to get image from element and set it as a background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one of possible solutions and one I'd probably go with myself:

1. Create directive, put all the code into post link function.
2. Store window vertical center coordinate.
3. Add `scroll` event listener on any list parent element.
4. Find current centermost element using [Document.elementFromPoint()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.elementFromPoint).
5. Assign active class to it, remove from previous one.

You also should not forget to maintain proper directive life cycle. That implies removing event listeners and dereferencing DOM nodes in order to prevent memory leaks.

The directive:

```
.directive("highlightCentermost", function ($window, $document, $timeout) {
  return function postLink (scope, el) {
    // References are kept here
    var center, centermost

    // Find and update centermost element
    function probe () {
      var newCentermost = $document[0].elementFromPoint(0, center)
      // No centermost assigned yet
      if (!centermost) {
        centermost = newCentermost
        centermost.classList.toggle("active", true)
        return
      }
      // Found another element
      if (centermost !== newCentermost) {
        // Remove class from old element
        centermost.classList.toggle("active", false)
        // Add class to new element
        newCentermost.classList.toggle("active", true)
        // Update the reference
        centermost = newCentermost
      } else if (!newCentermost && centermost) {
        // Cleanup if nothing was found
        centermost.classList.toggle("active", false)
        centermost = null
      }
    }

    function resize () {
      center = $window.innerHeight / 2
    }

    resize()
    // $timeout is required to wait until all element directives are applied
    $timeout(probe)
    $window.addEventListener("scroll", probe)
    $window.addEventListener("resize", resize)

    scope.$on("$destroy", function cleanup () {
      $window.removeEventListener("scroll", probe)
      $window.removeEventListener("resize", resize)
      centermost = null
    })
  }
})
```

[Full example at JSBin](http://jsbin.com/cifuxifoko/2/).

Pros:

1. You don't need to know collection size.
2. No need to check position of every DOM node.
3. Only one DOM operation per scroll.

Cons:

1. You have to micromanage what's over list items. Popup overlay might introduce more complexity, depending on what scrolls what.

Please note that this is the very basic version, you will probably want to improve functions that calculate vertical center and probe for element (like probe two points instead of one). I've used similar approach to implement `display:sticky` analogue in one of my applications, so it's pretty flexible.

There are more solutions I can come up with:

1. Check vertical position of every list item on scroll/animationFrame, update class if some criteria is met. Slow, but can handle dynamic height.
2. If list item height is constant, you can write function to calculate current criteria met element by `scrollTop` value. This is the mechanism behind virtual scroll (display only items in viewport, allows to have hu-u-uge amounts of items without performance impact).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to work Angular
But to get the middle element, you should try something like that.

Count elements length.
Divide the result per two.

You got the element at the center.
If you got something like 2.5, feel free to target to one before or after.

Comment: Sound nice. But first I will try with flexible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i created fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uwk46bky/1/ 
may it help :-)

```
<div ng-init="elements=['1','2','3','4','5']">
  <ul ng-repeat="element in  elements">
    <a class="row" >
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class="caption">
                <h4 ng-class="{'check':($index+0.5)==(elements.length/2)}">{{element}}</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:-

```
.check{
 background-color:red;   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for try but this element is not in the center of the screen. It is middle element.